# Query Last data group by column

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I have this data;

```
date        owner   p.code  product
----        -----   -----   ------
21.08.2020  Micheal   5    apple
22.08.2020  Micheal   5    apple
15.08.2020  George    4    biscuit
14.08.2020  George    4    biscuit
10.08.2020  Micheal   4    biscuit
23.08.2020  Alice     2    pear
15.08.2020  Alice     2    pear
14.08.2020  Micheal   2    pear
11.08.2020  Micheal   2    pear
```

I want to group them trought to product and show last date and last owner.

like this  ;

```
date         owner  p.code  product
----         -----   ------  ------
22.08.2020  Micheal    5    apple
15.08.2020  George     4    biscuit
23.08.2020  Alice      2    pear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by product order by date desc) rn 
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can phrase this using `group by`:

```
select product, code,
       max(date) as max_date,
       max(owner) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc) as owner_at_max_date
from t
group by product, code;
```

The [`keep`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) syntax is Oracle's rather verbose way of implementing a `first()` aggregation function.